# Como enviar notificações push/php com janela do site fechada?

Tags: navegador-de-internet, aplicação-desktop

De uns tempos para cá (acho que 2014 em diante), o facebook tem feito notificações via browser usando a API Notifications do HTML5. O curioso, é que facebook consegue mandar notificações, mesmo a sua página estando fechada.

Pesquisando na internet, não encontrei uma maneira sequer de fazer isso em conjunto com o PHP. Por isso estou apelando para o stackoverflow .

Sei que existem soluções como o PushLead, e o PushCrew. Mas de nada servem se quero usar meu próprio sistema. Usar somente exemplo do frontend, o script em si é inútil, sem uma linguagem que atue no servidor para enviar novidades aos usuários do site. Sobre tópicos semelhante já criado, nada servem para minha dúvida específica: Como enviar notificações push/php com janela do site fechada?

Comment: Como pretende receber notificações se o browser está fechado? Nesse caso as notificações seriam visualizadas onde?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para implementar este recurso utilize a Push API do Html5. Fique atento com a compatibilidade com os browsers.

Outro cuidado que deve ter é que o PHP não é uma linguagem boa para implementar daemons, isto é, implementar websockets é um tiro no pé. O PHP foi feito para que os processos iniciem e tenham um fim, manter um processo sempre ativo vai aumentar muito o uso de memória e processamento de seu servidor. Como o PHP não possui maneiras de gerenciar memória terá que contar apenas com o garbage collector, o que é uma péssima ideia. (Caso tenha alguma dúvida sobre isso, aqui uma explicação https://software-gunslinger.tumblr.com/post/47131406821/php-is-meant-to-die)

Apesar da Push API não utilizar websockets, tenha isso em mente, é melhor usar outra linguagem se deseja um sistema de notificações em tempo real. E tambem pense na situação que por trabalhar com workers, você receberá chamadas em tempos curtos de todos os usuários que habilitar este recurso, o que pode pesar em seu servidor devido ao alto número de processos que serão abertos conforme o número de usuários do seu site/sistema aumenta.

Por exemplo:

Se seu sistema possui 100 usuários e as notificações são conferidas de 5 em 5 segundos, o mínimo de requisição que terá é 100/s e 6000/m some isso a média de número de visitas em seu site por minuto e terá o total de processos executados. Chegará a conclusão que não é uma boa deixar esse tipo de recurso na mão do PHP, pois o processamento utilizado é muito alto.

Por isso irá encontrar poucos exemplos em PHP sobre recursos como notificações.

## Algumas implementações PHP

- https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php
- https://pusher.com/
- https://github.com/pusher-community/html5-realtime-push-notifications
- http://www.howopensource.com/2014/12/introduction-to-server-sent-events/
- https://github.com/licson0729/libSSE-php
- https://gauntface.github.io/simple-push-demo/

## Referências:

- https://w3c.github.io/push-api/
- https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/building-useful-notifications-with-html5-apis/163
- https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/push-notifications/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27221203/send-desktop-notifications-in-chrome-or-firefox-from-a-closed-web-app

Comment: Meu objetivo era criar um novo sistema de notificação para vloggers. Então acho que um sistema que envia uma notificação por dia seria o suficiente. Recentemente descobri que poderia fazer isso em AJAX (ainda sim consumindo recursos do servidor).
Sua ajuda contribui muito amigo. Ainda aceito sugestões.

Comment: Esse post me deixou com uma dúvida, será que dá pra juntar PHP + Cron do Linux pra empurrar as mensagens ao invés de deixar isso só com o PHP?